# How to sub-string a list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, substring

I have an assignment where I have a list with two names and I have to print the first name and then I have to print the last name.

```
names_list = ['Oluwaferanmi Fakolujo', 'Ajibola Fakolujo']
```

I have two names and then when I find the whitespace between them I have to print both the first name and the last name out of the list and put it into a variable.

I have tried to slice it but I don't understand it enough to use it. Here is an example:

```
substr = x[0:2]
```

This just brings both names instead of only substring it.

Comment: What is the desired result? Is it `['Oluwaferanmi', 'Ajibola']`?

Comment: oluwaferanmi is the name that is desired

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This will only work for Python 3.x**

You can use the `split()` method and indexing for these kinds of problems.

1. Iterate through the list
2. `split()` the string
3. Store the values in a variable, so that we can index them
4. Display the values

```py
names_list = ['Oluwaferanmi Fakolujo', 'Ajibola Fakolujo']

for i in names_list:

    string = i.split(" ")

    first_name = string[0]

    last_name = string[1]

    print(f"First Name: {first_name} Last Name: {last_name}")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
names_list = ['Oluwaferanmi Fakolujo', 'Ajibola Fakolujo']
for i in range(0, len(names_list)):
    nf = names_list[i].split(' ')
    name = nf[0]
    family = nf[1]
    print("Name is: {}, Family is: {}".format(name, family))
```

Output:

```
Name is: Oluwaferanmi, Family is: Fakolujo
Name is: Ajibola, Family is: Fakolujo
```

Comment: Is there a way to loop through this code so that i will be able to use it if i had like 20 names and i wanted the same output.

Comment: @oluwaferanmiFakolujo This code does what you want it to do.